# Heroku building app fail: error to load gem 'graphicsmagick'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems, graphicsmagick, minimagick

when I push my rails app to heroku it always fails. On the stage "Build App" the logs show me following message:

> checking for gm... no
>    !     rake aborted!
>    !     Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'graphicsmagick'.

I have required this gem in the Gemfile and I don't know why building app on heroku always fails.
Local running and running on CircleCI are ok.
Did someone have similar issue?

Please let me know what I've missed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the graphicsmagick Buildpack included?
Go to the settings tab on Heroku dashboard and add this url to your buildpacks: https://github.com/mcollina/heroku-buildpack-graphicsmagick.git

Comment: Thanks! I've been thinking about buildpack. But hoped there's another way to deal with graphicsmagick on heroku.