# Is there a way to install GraphicsMagick on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, graphicsmagick

I want to use gm package to generate thumbnail image (50x50) but I must install graphicsmagick in my Heroku server. So I googled it ,but haven't got a solution.

Comment: Install a buildpack! https://www.google.es/search?q=heroku+GraphicsMagic&oq=heroku+GraphicsMagic&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.867j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Try this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39212358/heroku-building-app-fail-error-to-load-gem-graphicsmagick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2021 Update:

I managed to install `GraphicsMagick` on my NodeJS Heroku project.

**You just have to add [heroku-buildpack-graphicsmagick](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/xerpa/heroku-buildpack-graphicsmagick)
 into your project.**

Right now there are a lot of methods, but the fastest one is:

1. Go to your Heroku Dashboard > Your Project > Settings tab
2. Scroll down to your Buildpacks section.
3. Add the buildpack .git link:

   https://github.com/xerpa/heroku-buildpack-graphicsmagick.git
4. Save and deploy your app again. Then it will be instaled.

Here's how it should look:
[image: Heroku]

Now it should work.

If you're interested in my case:
I was trying to add a library to create barcodes into a pdf. For that I used a library called `barcode` and `pdfkit`. Then in order for the barcode library to work, I had to have a working installation of GraphicsMagick. Then I discovered that I had to install this 'gm' dependency into my Heroku project.

Also, this is how it looks when deploying your project:

`GraphicsMagick app detected`

`+ install GraphicsMagick-1.3.19`

Answer (score -1):

I din't install anything on Heroku but It works I think GraphicsMagic is default

Comment: It's not a default. I had to install otherwise it was giving me building errors.  Like `Error: spawn gm ENOENT`